# can't publish a simple WCF service to my local machine using 1 click publish from visual studio 2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

build a very simple WCF service in visual studio 2010, build it , debug it successfully.
now, right click and click publish, fill in service URL with "local", and site/app with "Defualt Web Site/Demo", I got following erro message:

web deployment task failed.(the metabase path 'default Web Site/Demo' is not supported. path must be of the format '/lm/w3svc//ROOT/...'

that is the problem, thanks.